# How to get the nodes in red color with tcl script in NS2

Tags: tcl, nodes, ns2

I want to get which of the nodes are in red , so i have this script that do not execute.

```
for {set i 0} { $i < $14  } {incr i } {
if {$ns at 0.0 "$n($i) color red"}{
     return $n($i) 
    }
}
```

I am get this error:

> Error: missing close-blace: possible unbalanced brace in comment while executing.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Your code: Nothing similar in the ~2000 known simulations. Please do : `cd ns-2.35/tcl/ex/ && grep -Rn color *` ... to watch how to add color. ... A simple example is `simple-dyn.tcl` : Two colors. And you have another ~40 examples in `ex/*/`

Answer (score 0):

This line has two syntactic problems, one of which is causing the problem you currently have and one which will crop up as soon as you fix it. You need a space after the close brace in order to separate the expression word from the body word — Tcl cares about having spaces in critical places — and calls to commands inside `if` conditions need to be enclosed in square brackets.

```
if {$ns at 0.0 "$n($i) color red"}{
```

The minimal fix that might work is:

```
if {[$ns at 0.0 "$n($i) color red"]} {
```

I *suspect* that this won't work because the command doesn't give a boolean value, but until you add the brackets and a space it *definitely* won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: But i didn't get the nodes in red , do you have any tips to help me with.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of color settings to experiment with in e.g. ns-2.35/tcl/ex/wpan/wpan_demo5.tcl

Finding examples : `cd [folder-with-examples.tcl] && grep -n "color red" *`

AODV examples with red nodes: { aodv10ms.tcl, aodv10nodes.tcl, SoniaLamba-aodv.tcl } → [aodv-examples-06.17.tar.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNN1JzVDhWbVNCY28/view?usp=sharing) .... aodv10nodes.tcl snippet :

```
# Provide initial location of mobile nodes
$node_(0) set X_ 50.0
$node_(0) set Y_ 1.0
$node_(0) set Z_ 0.0
$node_(0) shape box
$node_(0) color red
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(0) shape box"
$ns_ at 0.0 "$node_(0) color red"
$ns_ at 0.5 "$node_(0) setdest 50.0 499.0 10.0"
```

All ~2000 examples are [here.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing)

Comment: thank you but i need to select red nodes and uses them later , it has to be a control structure .

Comment: @takwa mekni: »» i need to select red nodes and use them later «« : That's what the wpan examples do. Adding the colors during the simulation / the animation.